# How to add subdirectory in javacript_pack_tag from layout in rails 6 and Webpack?

Tags: webpack, webpack-4, ruby-on-rails-6

In rails 6 , I have `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'%>` in my layout. Since I have some other js files from subfolders that I want add separately
so I can split my js files, I tried `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'src/javascripts/other', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'%>` which is within packs folder. But the browser keep showing

> Webpacker can't find `src/javascripts/other` in ...

I tried a few other variation like `/`,`~other` etc., but without success.
Can anyone pls explain to what I am missing or the possible causes? Is there a better way to organise files and split codes that can include
any amount of files in layout manifest? Thanks
I am using rails 6, webpack 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/docs/folder-structure.md), if you have the following file:

`app/javascript/packs/admin/orders.js`

You can use :

```rb
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'admin/orders' %>
```

In your case, you should have:

`app/javascript/packs/src/javascripts/other.js`

Then you would be able to include it like this :

```rb
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'src/javascripts/other' %>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. My structure is exactly the same except that... instead of using default javascript folder ... I created my own Webpacker folder where I handle all my app assets using Webpacker. All assets both css and javacript in `Webpacker` folders working if layout reference pack_tag file is from directly under `Webpacker/packs`. Further subdirectories like `Webpacker/src/javascripts/other` won't work if I I put like `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'src/javascripts/other' %>` .

Comment: Wait, does that mean you put all your entry files in `Webpacker/packs/` ? If so `Webpacker/src` won't be recognized. In that case you need to specify something like (in your webpacker.yml):

`additional_paths: ['Webpacker/src/javascripts']`

Comment: Herz3h -Thank you taking your time to look into it. yes  my entry files are inside packs while I keep most of my js module in src path. I wasnt able get it work after trying additional_paths. I now imported module that has other module imported in it into `packs path` and it works fine. Ideally, as the projects become large, i'd like to have code splitted and use page specific js directly from their respect subdirectories and keep only main js that is shared across different pages in packs. But for now i think I am content with it .

Comment: Alright, you can mark your question as solved for future visitors then ;)